# Shortcut key for commenting out lines of Python code in Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I recently changed from the Enthought Canopy Python distribution to Anaconda, which includes the Spyder IDE.

In Canopy's code editor, it was possible to comment and uncomment lines of code by pressing the "Cntrl+/" shortcut key sequence. In Spyder I was unable to find an equivalent shortcut key in the introductory tutorial.

Is there a shortcut key for commenting and uncommenting code in Spyder?

Answer (score 183, accepted):

- **Single line comment**

  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>
- **Multi-line comment** select the lines to be commented

  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>
- **Unblock Multi-line comment**

  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd>

Comment: That's it, thanks. (The "single line" option also works if you select multiple lines; Ctrl+1 also uncomments the code in this case).

Comment: what do we do for spyder-notebook?

Comment: @imsrgadich you mean jupyter-notebook? If so, "ctrl+/" should do the job

Comment: @Suresh2692 thanks for replying. it doesn't work on jupyter-notebook at least with Finnish keyboard.

In fact there an spyder extension called `spyder-notebook` (https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-notebook)

Comment: Thanks for that info. this https://stackoverflow.com/a/38502057/4815313 may help you

Comment: This works, but according to pep8 standards, # should be followed bt an additional space for comments ctrl+1 does not add(or  remove) extra space after #. In Eclipse however, ctrl+\ does the job following pep8..

Answer (score 16):

On macOS:

```
Cmd + 1
```

On Windows, probably

```
Ctrl + (/) near right shift key
```

Comment: On Windows this does not work in Spyder. Instead, use Ctrl + 1, as suggested by other people.

Answer (score 6):

While the other answers got it right when it comes to add comments, in my case only the following worked.

- **Multi-line comment**

  <kbd>select the lines to be commented</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>
- **Multi-line uncomment**

  <kbd>select the lines to be uncommented</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a shortcut for commenting out lines in Python 3.6 (Spyder).

For Single Line Comment, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>. It will look like this `#This is a sample piece of code`

For multi-line comments, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>. It will look like this

`#============= 
\#your piece of code
\#some more code
\#=============`

Note : `\` represents that the code is carried to another line.

Answer (score 2):

- Unblock multi-line comment

  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>
- Multi-line comment

  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>

**NOTE: For my version of Spyder (3.1.4) if I highlighted the entire multi-line comment and used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> the block remained commented out. Only after highlighting a small portion of the multi-line comment did <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> work.**

Comment: you have to select only the code and uncomment, selecting the extra ##block and ctrl+5 did not work for me as well

Answer (score -7):

on Windows **F9** to run single line

Select the lines which you want to run on console and press **F9** button for multi line

Comment: The OP wants to comment a line, not to run it.

Comment: Yes Flame Denise i just explained about the Shortcut keys