# Jupyter Notebook, lines commented with triple quotes appear in [out]

Tags: python, jupyter

In Jupyter Notebook , i can see that multilines commenting with triples quotes such as:

```
''' multi
lines
commented
out'''
```

will be printed in the [out] cell.

Is there a way to prevent that from happening? (ie not having the commented out lines printed in the output?

Comment: That should only be printed if it's the only statement in the cell, if you have additional code following this then it should not be seen in the output

Comment: Comment them out using the comment marker `#`?  Triple quotes create strings not comments.

Comment: @ EdChum if i have code, and then the commented out lines they do show

Comment: Because IPython will insert a print statement before the string I guess.

Comment: I really don't see in what circumstance having a string  or a commented out such as that printed would be useful

Comment: Can you include the complete code where this is happening?

Comment: It's not inserting a `print` statement; jupyter notebook prints the last value calculated in each cell.  If you end a cell with a string literal, it will echo that on the [out].

Comment: @wildwilhelm ok so if i want to comment out the bottom of the cell for debug purpose i will always have a slew of letters in the output, there is no way around that?

Comment: Your fundamental misunderstanding is that a triple quote is not a comment, it is a string value, and like any value in a notebook will be printed out.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As mentioned by @snakecharmerb, you can comment out the lines (with `#`) instead of wrapping them in a string.  There is a [keyboard shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30981483/1062499) for this: select the code that you want to comment (or uncomment, it's a toggle), and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>.

Alternatively, you can put a semicolon (`;`) after your close-quote to [suppress the output](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/tips.html#suppress-output) of the string literal.