# Shortcut to comment out multiple lines in Jupyter Ipython notebook on Mac with French keyboard layout (without numpad)?

Tags: macos, jupyter-notebook, keyboard-shortcuts, comments, french

I'm trying to select and comment `#` multiple lines using Jupyter Notebook on Mac with French keyboard layout and no numpad.

To type the slash (`/`) on this keyboard, the shortcut is `Shift` + `:`

When trying to comment lines on Jupyter:

- with `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `:` it doesn't work
- Neither `Ctrl` + `#`
- Or `Cmd` + `:`
- or `Cmd` + `Shift` + `:`

However on a Chromebook with French keyboard layout I'm able to do `Cmd` (search key) + `:` and it works fine.

I'm aware of this question: [How do I comment out multiple lines in Jupyter Ipython notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29885371/how-do-i-comment-out-multiple-lines-in-jupyter-ipython-notebook) but wondering if a keyboard shortcut solution has been found for Mac with French keyboard layout and no numpad?

**EDIT**: open issue on Github: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3753

Answer (score 3):

In my case, `Ctrl`+ `§` worked (with Switzerland keyboard no numeric keypad)

Answer (score 1):

@Jean: the jupyter notebook shortcut may be overwritten by the Mac View menu shortcut for Hide bar.

Answer (score 0):

On a Windows 10 laptop (no numeric keypad) with portuguese layout the combination is **Ctrl** + **~** to comment/uncomment a multiple line selection

Answer (score 0):

MacOs, QWERTY Keyboard (IT): `Ctrl + .`

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS with Spanish keyboard `CTRL + -` works for me.