# Comment various code lines in a laptop without numpad or "/" in JupyterNotebook (Spanish keyboard layout)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter-lab

I have previously checked this thread and none of the answers worked [Shortcut to comment out multiple lines in Jupyter Ipython notebook on Mac with French keyboard layout (without numpad)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59226860/shortcut-to-comment-out-multiple-lines-in-jupyter-ipython-notebook-on-mac-with-f)

My laptop does not have a numbers pad, so I cannot press the `/` key to comment `#` various lines in JupyterLab/JupyterNotebook. Holding the `shift key` + `7` to input the `/` does not work. I have tried multiple combinations without succeess.

I'm using a Spanish keyboard layout.

I dunno if someone have solved this issue. It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In Python the multiline quote `"""` can be used to "comment" multiple lines of code.