# Comment Jupyter Azerty Mac

Tags: python, comments, jupyter, shortcut

I have just switched to a Mac with french AZERTY, and some shortcuts in Jupyter don't work. Comment which is ctrl+/ doesn't do anything.

If I do cmd+maj+: which should be equivalent to cmd+/ doesnt comment the line of code.

Note that I am using the jupyter of coursera.

thanks!

Comment: Exact same issue here. After inquiring it would seem that it's indeed related to AZERTY keyboard. Not the case in any other code program, only in Jupyter

Comment: So what do we do ?

Comment: I created an issue on Jupyter GitHub issue tracker. Please upvote it and help the team solving it by providing info.

Comment: @bolino link please ?

Comment: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/6060

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29885371/how-do-i-block-comment-in-jupyter-notebook, it happens on any non-English MacOS keyboard.